# Unrecognised option '-get-url' Error splitting the argument list: Option not found

Tags: command-line, ffmpeg, youtube-dl

I'm trying to download a clip from a YouTube video, and I've gone the route of command line tools after I found out websites aren't cut out for this task.

Thanks to this [AskUbuntu thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/970629/how-to-download-a-portion-of-a-video-with-youtube-dl-or-something-else), I've got the following command:

```
ffmpeg -i $(youtube-dl -f 22 --get-url https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EkTHhk07nv4) -ss 00:05:12.70 -t 00:00:08.10 -c:v copy -c:a copy hamster.mp4
```

However, after running it with `ffmpeg` and `youtube-dl` in the same directory, and cmd running in the same directory, I get this output:

```
ffmpeg version git-2020-02-06-343ccfc Copyright (c) 2000-2020 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 9.2.1 (GCC) 20200122
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-sdl2 --enable-fontconfig --enable-gnutls --enable-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libdav1d --enable-libbluray --enable-libfreetype --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libzimg --enable-lzma --enable-zlib --enable-gmp --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libmysofa --enable-libspeex --enable-libxvid --enable-libaom --enable-libmfx --enable-ffnvcodec --enable-cuvid --enable-d3d11va --enable-nvenc --enable-nvdec --enable-dxva2 --enable-avisynth --enable-libopenmpt --enable-amf
  libavutil      56. 39.100 / 56. 39.100
  libavcodec     58. 68.100 / 58. 68.100
  libavformat    58. 38.100 / 58. 38.100
  libavdevice    58.  9.103 / 58.  9.103
  libavfilter     7. 74.100 /  7. 74.100
  libswscale      5.  6.100 /  5.  6.100
  libswresample   3.  6.100 /  3.  6.100
  libpostproc    55.  6.100 / 55.  6.100
```

Followed by this error:

```
Unrecognized option '-get-url'.
Error splitting the argument list: Option not found
```

I've been unable to make sense of the error message, and searching for the error didn't give me any answers either. What could be wrong with the command?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I've been unable to make sense of the error message, and searching for the error didn't give me any answers either. What could be wrong with the command?

`ffmpeg` is attempting to parse the `--get-url` option intended for `youtube-dl`.

**Explanation**

The `youtube-dl` portion embedded in the `ffmpeg` command ex.:

```
$(youtube-dl -f 22 --get-url https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EkTHhk07nv4)
```

is intended to:

1. Execute the `youtube-dl` command (which returns a URL necessary to access the YouTube video).
2. Substitute the results (i.e. the video URL returned) at the given point in the `ffmpeg` command.

Your issue seems to be that the `$()` syntax isn't being used to obtain/substitute the correct URL. So `ffmpeg` is reading the raw `youtube-dl` command and attempting to parse `youtube-dl` options that weren't intended for it.

**A Possible Solution**

One thing to be aware of is that `$()` isn't part of `ffmpeg`. That is, `ffmpeg` is not what is running `youtube-dl` or substituting the results.

In the case of Linux, whichever shell Linux is using does the execution and substitution before passing things along to `ffmpeg`.

It isn't clear to me which OS you're using, but I notice that you make a reference to "cmd" in your original post. If you are on Windows, `cmd` (the native Windows command prompt) doesn't support using `$()`. Instead, you should try your command with `powershell`:

```
powershell ffmpeg -i $(youtube-dl -f 22 --get-url https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EkTHhk07nv4) -ss 00:05:12.70 -t 00:00:08.10 -c:v copy -c:a copy hamster.mp4
```

**Path Notes**

Please note that using the `powershell` option above "as-is" assumes that `ffmpeg` and `youtube-dl` are available system-wide (i.e. the folders in which their respective executables reside are part of your Windows Path settings).

If you wish to add these folders to your Path, [you can find a quick tutorial on how to do that here](https://www.architectryan.com/2018/08/31/how-to-change-environment-variables-on-windows-10/). Just make sure to add them to your System variables. Also, as  a side note, you should restart Windows Explorer before attempting to use either `ffmpeg` or `youtube-dl` (this is often done with a reboot).

If you don't wish to make `ffmpeg` and `youtube-dl` available system-wide, you can modify the `powershell` command above with the respective paths to `ffmpeg.exe` and `youtube-dl.exe`. For instance, to use everything in the same folder, you could add `.\` in front of each executable name:

```
powershell .\ffmpeg -i $(.\youtube-dl -f 22 --get-url https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EkTHhk07nv4) -ss 00:05:12.70 -t 00:00:08.10 -c:v copy -c:a copy hamster.mp4
```

Comment: Ah! I didn't know the substitution syntax wasn't supported! In hindsight, the fact that I found it on AskUbuntu should've tipped me off...
Though I'm having problems using this answer as well: `powershell`, even when ran in the same directory, doesn't recognise either `ffmpeg` or `youtube-dl` as a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program, even when I use the exact command you sent in the exact same directory as before. Adding `.exe` doesn't change the error either. Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: I've updated my answer. But in short, the `powershell` command above assumes that `ffmpeg` and `youtube-dl` are part of your Windows Path settings (environment variables). Or rather, the folders that contain them are. If this isn't the case, you'll need to add the paths to each executable in the command. For the "current folder", you can use .\ instead of typing out the full path (if you wish).

Comment: Ah, that worked, thank you so much for helping!

Comment: Glad to assist. =)